# Один BufferedReader и Random на несколько классов

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Пишу программу для формирования пароля и угадывания слова пользователя путём перебора случайных символов из алфавита. Пользователь определяет длину будущего пароля и задаёт своё слова для угадывания. В обоих частях программы используется BufferedReader и случайное число. Что-бы не обьявлять вышеуказанные функции каджый раз я вынесу их в отдельный класс и впоследствии буду только обращаться к ним когда необходимо.

```
    MainClass.java
    public static void main(String[] args){
    GetStarted(); // "ухожу" от main класса чтобы после выполнения задачи опять вернутся к новому выбору 
    }
    
   public static void GetStarted(){
    System.out.println("Выбирайте - "1" для нового пароля и "2" для угадывания слова")
    String functionNumber = new BufferedReaderClass().reader(Integer.parseInt()); // этой строкой я хочу вызывать из класса BufferedReaderClass каждый раз новый экземпляр reader-а, но скобки parseInt() подчёркивает красным 

    if(functionNumber.eqvals("1"){
    createNewPassword();
     }
    if(functionNumber.eqvals("2"){
    guessMyWord();
     }
    }
```

Отдельный класом прописан BufferedReader

```
    BufferedReaderClass.java

    public BufferedReader reader() {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    return reader;
     }
```

Несмотря на то, что я возвращаю reader мой GetStarted() не работает.
И вообще есть ли смысл разделять программу на разные классы если она очень маленькая?

Comment: У вас код не должен даже компилироваться. Тут явная ошибка: `"Выбирайте - "1" для нового пароля и "2" для угадывания слова"`, т.к. кавычки нужно экранировать или использовать вместо двойных кавычек одинарные

Comment: Я так написал для экономии времени, в коде я обращаюсь к отдельному классу StringStore и из него "достаю" необходимые слова и символы. Спасибо, но проблема не в этом

Comment: Умеете запутать и это не хорошо для вопроса, т.к. может отпугнуть тех, кто не захочет решать паззлы, чтобы понять в чем у вас вопрос :) А так, у вас семантика метода не предполагает каких либо параметров `public BufferedReader reader()`, а в коде вы пытаетесь передать `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: Да, я сильно запутался. Если упростить вопрос то "Как прописать класс BufferedReader и запрос к нему что-бы они работали из любого места программы"

Comment: Пусть `MainClass.java` и `BufferedReaderClass.java` будут в одной папке. Сделайте в `BufferedReaderClass` метод так `public BufferedReader reader() { return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); }` и тестовый запуск из `main` метода в `MainClass`: `String functionNumber = new BufferedReaderClass().reader().readLine();` `System.out.println(functionNumber);`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Четыре часа потратил а всё было так просто!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть **MainClass.java** и **BufferedReaderClass.java** будут в одной папке.

Сделайте в **BufferedReaderClass** метод:

```
public BufferedReader reader() {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}
```

Тестовый запуск из **main** метода в **MainClass**:

```
String functionNumber = new BufferedReaderClass().reader().readLine();
System.out.println(functionNumber);
```

---

Но в этом виде есть ненужное создание объекта, поэтому предлагаю `reader` сделать статичным:

```
public static BufferedReader reader() {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}
```

А вызывать так:

```
String functionNumber = BufferedReaderClass.reader().readLine();
System.out.println(functionNumber);
```